# Forcing Gatsby to exclude one component in /pages

Tags: gatsby, git-submodules

I have a submodule I'm trying to include in my Gatsby Project.  The submodule passes html into an iframe which is then used on the site.

When I build my project, everything works as expected. When I access `/component`, gatsby resolves it via the path: `/public/component/`. It loads the correct html, generates the iframe, and everything is good to go.

When on development however, trying to access `/component` attempts to resolve by going to `/pages/component`, which is not correct.

Adding the submodule directly to `pages` doesn't work, because then it is forced to go through all of the minification/optimization and seems to cause other issues as well.

So I need some way to either force Gatsby to always to use `/public/component` even when running in development mode.

I've looked at pretty much everything I could find online and haven't been able to find any answers.